# Serializing an object with Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am trying to serialize an object with Newtonsoft Json converter like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 string json = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                jlpt = "5"
            });
```

but it gives me an error saying that

> SerializeObject does not exist.

However, when I click to check the reference I see it.

Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the `new` - at the moment your code is referring to `SerializeObject` as if it were the name of a type.

Comment: You can also get rid of the ```Newtonsoft.Json.``` since you have ```using Newtonsoft.Json```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `new` instance creation of `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert`, because `SerializeObject` is a static method you don't need create a instance of the `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` to use it

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                jlpt = "5"
            });
```

also if you add `using Newtonsoft.Json;` to the program then you simply use like this

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                jlpt = "5"
            });
```